# Issue in resolving nonnull and notnull symbol in looper.java

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an android app please help me to solve dependency error.

```
package android.os;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

I've add following dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: did you resolved the issue? none of the provided issue below worked in my case

Comment: A modern take on this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470474/cannot-resolve-symbol-nonnull-after-android-studio-update

Answer (score 16):

Add following in your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
```

Also, verify this

Go to File -> Setting -> search for "nullable" and verify these settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get an error: `Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds`. Removed the `:+`.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: Rather than using "+", you can use specific version.

Answer (score 7):

Since Google announced at IO17 gradle:3.0, the `compile` configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by `implementation` or `api`

So prefer

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    ...
}
```

or greater version

Answer (score 5):

Add following in your dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

Also add gradle build as other guys already mentioned:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of android api 29 ('targetSdkVersion' 29) com.android.support has been moved to 'androidx' library.
In your Build.gradle file(app level), dependencies block use...

dependencies{
...

implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
}

And in your .java files use import as follows:
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
...

Again build your project!