# cannot resolve symbol in barcode activity

Tags: java, android, barcode, symbols, google-vision

I'm trying to implement google's barcode scanner within my application.

The following code calls the barcode activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.read_barcode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BarcodeCaptureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.AutoFocus, autoFocus.isChecked());
        intent.putExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.UseFlash, useFlash.isChecked());

        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

It then jumps to this part of the Activity.java code:

[image]

It throws the flag `Source code does not match byte code` and returns to the calling function where it then crashes with an `InflationException` that points to an XML file.

On further inspection, many of the imports are red:

[image]

As a result, there are many error flags on Activity.java. The code still compiles and runs up until the `OnClick` method is hit. I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201143/cannot-resolve-symbol-nonnull-and-notnull-in-looper-java/35201197) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990752/source-code-does-not-match-the-bytecode-when-debugging-on-a-device) on SO to no success. TIA

Comment: Many source files in the ADK are just stubs.

Comment: @Henry what exactly does that mean?

Comment: They just have the same method signatures (to allow your program to be compiled) but are otherwise shrunk down.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Android emulator (or real device) with the same api level as the compileSdkVersion in your Gradle file.

Comment: I started at my physical device's API level but changed it at the suggestion of other people's working solutions. So far, this has not had any net effect on the ability to run my code.

Comment: I assume if you use real device you might have different code since every company would compile the code by themself. Can you try this with emulator?

Comment: An emulator wouldn't work for me, I need a specific internet connection to run the app. This leaves me to using a work tablet as my physical device.

Comment: If you need a specific port you can do 'adb forward ..'