# cloud fire store android X incompatibility problem in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pubspec

I'm using `flutter version 1.22.6` to run my flutter app .. and have  some packages including

```
  cloud_firestore: 0.16.0+1
```

everything runs fine and `flutter pub get` completed successfully, but when I try to run the app I get this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431961/my-flutter-app-doesnt-compile-anymore-due-to-cloud-firestore-and-firebase-auth-e) question in StackOverflow having a similar issue which can help in resolving the issue you’re facing.

Found another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67778813) in which it is suggested to look into the following [github issue](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/223#issuecomment-790656288) and update the below line in the `[Project Directory]/android/build.gradle` as:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

And after that it’s suggested to run the below commands in your `project directory`:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

Then as a final step build the project again.